# Testing a stored procedure which uses collection types

Tags: sql, unit-testing, collections, types, oracle11g

```
PROCEDURE test_max_rows (
    test_out OUT NOCOPY test_col_t,
    test_in  IN         test_t,
    max_rows IN         NUMBER DEFAULT 1000;
)
IS
    CURSOR cur_test ( max_rows IN number ) IS
        SELECT id FROM test_table
        WHERE test_in.key_id = 'ABC'
        AND test_in.curr_nm IS NOT NULL
        AND max_rows < 1 OR ROWNUM <= max_rows;
BEGIN
    OPEN  cur_test( NVL(max_rows, 1000) ) ;
    FETCH cur_test BULK COLLECT INTO test_out;
    CLOSE cur_test ;
END test_max_rows;
/
```

`test_t` is an object type with the following definition:

`test_t`:

```
DATE_FROM TIMESTAMP
DATE_TO   TIMESTAMP
CD        col_t
CURR_NM   col_t
VAL       VARCHAR2( 40 )        
KEY_ID    NUMBER
```

`col_t` is a collection type with following definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE COL_T IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(200);
```

I have not worked with collections and want to test this proc by creating a PL/SQL anonymous block to verify that it outputs the correct number of rows when passed with different values for max_rows.

max_rows: 500  Rows Returned: 500

max_rows: 10000  Rows Returned: 10000

max_rows: -1  Rows Returned: All fetched by the Select Query in the cursor.

I am not sure how to pass values for object and collection types in the anonymous block. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to declare a collection variable of the same type; and declare and populate an object to pass;

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
  result test_col_t;
  input test_t;
BEGIN
  input := new test_t(null, null, null, new test_col_t(), null, 'ABC');
  test_max_rows(result, input, 50);
  dbms_output.put_line('Rows returned: ' || result.count);
END;
/
```

You don't need to initialise the collection as it's an `OUT` parameter in the procedure, but you do need to initialise the `IN` parameter. I've left the object attributes you aren't using as null for now. You could define a `NUMBER` variable to pass as the `max_rows` number if you prefer.

I've stuck with `ABC` for the ID as that's what your query is looking for, but in your object definition it's a number, so you'll either need to change the type or set it to (and test for) a number instead. This runs with the definition you showed (with typos corrected, like removing the semicolon after `DEFAULT 1000`) if `KEY_ID` defined as a `VARCHAR2` instead of a `NUMBER`.

Comment: Thanks @Alex. I have edited the question a bit. Can you please help further.

Comment: @WamglindCarmasaic - there are some issues with what you posted, but I've fixed my block to pass an object in as well, with a few minor tweaks to account for those issues.

Comment: @WamglindCarmasaic - I suspect you meant your edit to change to `WHERE user_id = test_in.key_id`, so those types need to be consistent. Testing whether `curr_nm` is null looks a bit odd though as it isn't related to the rows in the table.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes I meant that.

Comment: Hi @Alex. I know this is asking for a little too much. But I just wanted to connect with you via email because some questions I can't really post here due to company policies. Drop a mail to: abhinav.verma88@gmail.com, if its fine by you. Thanks anyways. You are a great help here as well:)

Comment: @WamglindCarmasaic - if it can't be posted in public, it shouldn't be put in an email either (as that is not secure), nor discussed in chat when you get enough rep to do that. There is really no scope on SO for private communication anyway, and I'm afraid it's not something I'm interested in, sorry. It's often possible to create a generic, simplified (as a bonus!) version of something to get help with, and then apply that to your real situation. Sometimes just creating a simple demo reveals the problem anyway.